# MySQL what is the maximum size of a database?

Tags: mysql

I have looked all over the MySQL website and found no definitive answers.

1. Is the size of the database determined by the operating system or is there 4GB limit?
2. Where can I find perforamnce statistics against other databases (sqlServer, oracle ect)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/table-size-limit.html - also see the plethora of similar questions to the right, under **Related**.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html):

> E.10.3. Limits on Table Size
>
> The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits. The following table lists some examples of operating system file-size limits. This is only a rough guide and is not intended to be definitive. For the most up-to-date information, be sure to check the documentation specific to your operating system.

```
Operating System                     File-size Limit
Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32                   2GB/4GB
Win32 w/ NTFS                        2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit               2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+  (using ext3 file system) 4TB
Solaris 9/10                         16TB
MacOS X w/ HFS+                      2TB
```

> Windows users, please note that FAT and VFAT (FAT32) are not considered suitable for production use with MySQL. Use NTFS instead.
>
> On Linux 2.2, you can get MyISAM tables larger than 2GB in size by using the Large File Support (LFS) patch for the ext2 file system. Most current Linux distributions are based on kernel 2.4 or higher and include all the required LFS patches. On Linux 2.4, patches also exist for ReiserFS to get support for big files (up to 2TB). With JFS and XFS, petabyte and larger files are possible on Linux.

As for the other part of your question, a few thoughts:

1. It's a broad, complex, multi-factorial question. Consider narrowing the scope of the question to MySQL and one other RDBMS (eg. SQL Server) and probably even one particular feature.
2. Google is your friend.
3. Vendors tend to publish their own biased comparisons. Take vendor numbers with a grain of salt.

Comment: Ok so there are constraints on tables sizes but none on the database itsself? Is that correct?

Comment: @stackoverflow: None are mentioned in the ["Limits in MySQL" section of the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limits.html).

Comment: _Today's machines do not have limits like what is shown in that quote._

Comment: Thanks, Google, for bringing me to "2. Google is your friend".

Answer (score 3):

1- With respect to database size, the limit is dependent on Operating System file size. Please see this [article](http://nickduncan.co.za/maximum-mysql-database-size/) 

 2- The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits. ([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html))

3- You may google for MySQL vs SQL Server Vs Oracle, also check this [link](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/oracle-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server.html)

Comment: With `PARTITIONing`, it is possible to exceed the OS file size limit.

Answer (score 3):

With today's hardware and OS, together with MySQL's preferred Engine InnoDB, the *table* size limitation is 64TB.  With `PARTITIONing`, that can be stretched to over a hundred petabytes.

A *database* is a collection of *tables*.  So, to answer the title question literally, we need to go beyond the max table size.  Since there can be thousands of tables in a database, we are now into the exabyte stratosphere.

See also [*Hard limits in MySQL*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits) .

Answer (score 2):

default mysql is 256 TB for myd file with 6 byte pointer size. i know this is ridiculous answer, but that is what you wanted to know. in real life all depends on the queries, indexes, column count, row count, etc.. i guess.

Comment: Where are you getting your information? And what platform does this refer to? According to the docs on the MySQL website, 256TB would not be a default value https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: @Chris - Eh?  That link says "You are using a MyISAM table and the space required for the table exceeds what is permitted by the internal pointer size. MyISAM permits data and index files to grow up to 256TB by default, but this limit can be changed up to the maximum permissible size of 65,536TB (2567 − 1 bytes)."