# In linux , mysql memory maximum limit in Local server computer

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to know that what will be the maximum memory storage of **mysql** in **linux** OS?

i tried to do research on that but no proper answers so plzz help to find out......

Answer (score 0):

Question answered before:

```
Operating System                     File-size Limit
Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32                   2GB/4GB
Win32 w/ NTFS                        2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit               2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+  (using ext3 file system) 4TB
Solaris 9/10                         16TB
MacOS X w/ HFS+                      2TB
```

Info coming from this link below:

[MySQL what is the maximum size of a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436246/mysql-what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-database)